# Count the values in list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to count the values in list of dictionaries with the condition matching

```
test_dicts = [
    {
        'int_count': 1,
        'code': ['500'],
        'unique_id': '11',
    },
    {
        'int_count': 1,
        'code': ['201'],
        'unique_id': '11',
    },
    {
        'int_count': 6,
        'code': ['202', '200', '201', '205', '226', '228'],
        'unique_id': '11',
    },
    {
        'int_count': 1,
        'code': ['303'],
        'unique_id': '12',
    },
    {
        'int_count': 5,
        'code': ['309', '301', '203', '208', '252'],
        'unique_id': '12',
    }
]
```

The output I am expecting based on summing the `int_count` of items with the same `unique_id`:

```
Output = [{'unique_id':11, 'int_count':8}, {'unique_id':12, 'int_count':6}
```

Comment: Your example `test_dict` isn't syntactically correct.  What's the condition you're trying to match on?

Comment: ah, I think I figured it out.  Going to edit your post to fix it.

Comment: Is `'portname'` `'unique_id'` too?

Comment: is fine if you get {'11':8, '12':6},  ? using a list of dicts in this case is  not the best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `defaultdict` to collect the counts and then produce the list in the desired format:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for d in test_dicts:
    counts[d['unique_id']] += d['int_count']

print([
    {'unique_id': unique_id, 'int_count': int_count}
    for unique_id, int_count in counts.items()
])
```

Comment: Didn't know `defaultdict` was a thing - deleting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Rephrasing question:

I'm going to simplify your input a little more, since there is a funny key, and the lists seem to be ignored (not checked for uniqueness).

```
values = [
    {'count': 1, 'id': '11'},
    {'count': 1, 'id': '11'},
    {'count': 6, 'id': '11'},
    {'count': 1, 'id': '12'},
    {'count': 5, 'id': '12'},
]
```

The question then is to group by `'id`' and sum `'count'`, e.g.:

```
assert res == [{'id':11, 'count':8}, {'id':12, 'count':6}]
```

### Answer

You can do this in many ways, but for nearly all cases it will be clean and fast to use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

# Get results
counts = Counter()
for val in values:
    counts[val['id']] += val['count']

# Change to desired output format
res = [{'id': k, 'count': v} for k, v in counts.items()]
```